# What is the time complexity of min-heap based solution to calendar rendering problem

Tags: algorithm-analysis, heaps

Question:  You are given a set of events in a day.  Each event has a start and end time.  Find the maximum number of concurrent events

Solution:

1. First convert events into an array of "Event objects".  Each object has a Time field and EventType(start/End) field.  (O(N)
2. Min-heapify the array, with time as the key to order the elements. O(N)
3. Until heap is empty, do a removeMin(). if event is start increment numConcurrent, if it is a end decrement numConcurrent.  Keep track of max value of numConcurrent.  O(N*Logn)

SO, complexity is O(N * logN).  Is this analysis correct?  The interviewer told me thatI need to do it using sort to get O(N*logN).  I don't see why because above solution achieves the same.

Comment: Putting everything in a heap and then extracting everything is sorting. I don't understand what your interviewer meant. Note that since calendars usually store events with (at best) minute precision, you can use a linear sorting algorithm.

Comment: 1) I don't see how this algorithm solves the problem. 2) Do you have a conceptual question? Just checking your solution does not make a good question.

Comment: Can you comment on why the solution is incorrect?